# Flutter Provider and sqflite integration

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, sqflite

I have a sqflite table in flutter app to store user details. For state management of the application I'm using provider. I have two models in this application one for api calls and another for sqflite tables.

This is the model for getting user data from api

```
// PS. The class structure
    class UserDetails {
      String? id;
      bool? mobileVerified;
      String? resentOtp;
      String? email;
      String? regmail;
      List<UserDeviceDetails>? deviceDetails;
      List<UserLocationDetails>? locationDetails;
      List<String>? deviceId;
      String? userValidCode;
      String? leadstatus;
      bool? dailyMail;
      bool? weeklyMail;
      bool? promotionalMail;
      bool? trValid;
      String? userType;
      String? createdAt;
      String? updatedAt;
      int? otp;
      bool? emailVerified;
      List<UserAccount>? accounts;
    }
```

The Model for user table is as follows

```
class UserTable {
  int? id;
  String? accountDetails;
  String? accountId;
  String? childName;
  String? childGender;
  int? expiry;
  int? finalSequenceNo;
  int? packageIndex;
  String? parentName;
  String? productType;
  String? userId;
  int? age;
  int? dob;
  int? nextSyncTime;
  String? productSubType;
  String? validTill;
  int? latestUpdatePkgSeqNo;
  int? guidedTour;
}
```

For checking (inside splashscreen) if the user is logged and routing i'm depending upon this usertable and also pushing value to provider from this table.

```
 _dbHelper.getAllUserData().then((value) {
      String routeName = value.length > 0
          ? HomeScreen.routeName
          : IntroductionScreen.routeName;
      print('navigate to next page' + routeName);
      if(value.length>0){
        Provider.of<UserProvider>(context,listen: false).setuserProvider(value[0]);
      }
```

The above code push values to provider if there values exists in table. What i'm having trouble is when the user logs in for the first time(now i need to restart the app for provider to get the values ). I want values to be pushed into the provider at the same time the data stores to the usertable. The provider is given below.

```
class UserProvider with ChangeNotifier{
  UserTable? user;
  void setuserProvider(UserTable userdata){
    user=userdata;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  UserTable? get userdata{
    return user;
  }
}

  //Function to insert details inside user table
  Future  _insertuserDetails(UserDetails? userDetails) async{
      if(userDetails != null){
         await _dbhelper!.insertUserDetails(userDetails);
```

Im inserting values of userdetails to userTable(table) using insertfunction. How can I pass the same to provider

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same function when the user logged in (that is your login screen). maybe your question is how to excess the provider in the splash screen and login screen.
I am not getting your question clearly but the below things may help you

1. put your provider on"main.dart" in your AppState()class
2. now you can access it in your login screen and store value when the user hits the submit button.

"main.dart" file

```
Future<void> main() async {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
        providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
            create: (context) => YourProvider(),
          ),
          ],child:
        MaterialApp(
      title: 'MyApp',
      home: SplashScreen(),
      routes: {
      AppConstant.ROUTE_LOGIN_SCREEN: (ctx) => LOGINSCREEN(),
      }
      )
    ) 
    
    
}
```

"Login.dart"
onSubmit pressed

```
onPressed:(){
// make function for user input
 Provider.of<UserProvider>(context,listen: false).setuserProvider("your value");
}
```

Comment: The value comes from api in the form of  **userDetail** . The provider contains the model **UserTable** .  so pushing value to provider from usertable to provider is working. During Login time I need the same. I mean data comes as **userDetail** I want to push to provider in the form of **UserTable**

Comment: then you have to assign the value from userDetail model to UserTable manually. then pass the value in the function . ex. userDetail.id = UserTable.id;